# How to insert image between layers in html5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I need to be able to layer image in canvas... how it is possible to insert image between two, or order the image, more like layer in photoshop... on top or below. In fact, i alredy draw many images, i need to be able to inser one between those, or just use a dummy and change it later, i dont know

what is the way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to just stack all of your elements inside a parent container and adjust the `z-index` CSS property of each layer.

The higher the `z-index`, the closer the layer is to the top of the stack. Elements with lower `z-index` values are obstructed by elements with higher values.

Note that you'll likely have to set `position: absolute;` on each layer within the container and then align them to, say, the top left corner of the parent element. Otherwise they won't overlap one another.

Alternatively, you can manage the layers based on their position within the DOM tree. The later the element is defined in the DOM, the closer it will be to the top of your layer stack (CSS properties aside, of course). So, you could theoretically use `insertBefore()` or a homespun `insertAfter()` to place your layers in the required location within the DOM and avoid `z-index` manipulation.